# My CPU is still faster than my GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance

When I render something with blender my CPU is faster than my GPU. Why is that? 
My GPU is Nvidia Geforce GT730 2gb  and my CPU is intel i5

Comment: This is frustrating  I have a macbook pro but I bought a Lenovo pc  with intel i5 and nvidia GPU just for faster rendering but it is not.

Comment: This is related and may awnser your question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24272/gpu-slower-than-cpu

Comment: What rendering engine are you using?

Comment: @PGmath I'm using cycles render

Comment: The [tag:blender-internal] tag is for the blender internal (BI) render engine.

Comment: So you mean it works only with blender render ?

Comment: No, that's just what that tag on our site is for.

Comment: If I read the specs correctly, the GT730 is a pretty slow graphics card. It provides hardware acceleration for multimedia applications (["super-fast web browsing, plus incredible photo and video editing"](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-730)) but it is not meant for high performance calculations. They compare it to integrated graphics, which is like comparing a Smart to an old VW Beetle, while everyone else is driving Ferrari.

Comment: That explains a lot. I have never read its specs all I know that it is 2 gb. Now I know that I have to change it. Any recommendations?

Comment: There is a rendering benchmark [on Blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239480) that lists rendering times for different grahics cards and processors. Maybe the spreadsheet can give you some orientation, then you will have to pick one that fits you budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase your tile size.

[image]

Your CPU is like Usain Bolt, and your GPU is a lot of turtles. Enough turtles will cover more total distance travelled than Usain Bolt going at full speed within the same time.

Likewise, your GPU will process more pixels at the same time, although slower, so increase the tile size.

You will need to experiment, though, with various values. You will need to find that sweet spot for your GPU and scene. If your values are too high, your GPU might not have enough cores to process an entire tile in one shot, so you might get that lag.

**UPDATE**

Your GPU has 96 cores running at 700 MHz. This explains why you may not be getting a very big GPU benefit no matter how you tweak the tile size.

In comparison, today's latest budget NVidia GPU is the GTX 950, which has 768 cores, running at a slightly higher 1024 MHz.

I advise you to upgrade your GPU.

Comment: I did that and it was kinda helpful but the cpu renders 4 tiles while gpu renders only one tile

Comment: Did you time your results? You may want to consider either sticking to your CPU or get a new GPU.

Comment: After increasing the size of the tiles the cpu became much faster than before but the gpu not that difference

Comment: GTX 950 , is it the in price and specs? Or is there a better one ?

Comment: GTX 950 is around the $135-$160 range. If you're willing to shell out around $500+, you can go for a GTX 980. Also, note that Blender Cycles may now support Radeon cards, but stick with NVidia (my bias).