# What would be the better hardware to use in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, workflow, customization

So, i have a dilemma. Do i use my i3 4160 or the soon to be mine gtx 960 to render out scenes and animations in blender cycles, please any answers would be helpful

EDIT thanks for all the advise guys, ill look into this a bit more then.

Comment: The difference between rendering speed depends on the scene itself. Some scene will render faster on CPU and other on GPU and viceversa. See related question: [GPU slower than CPU?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24272/gpu-slower-than-cpu) I would suggest to render some frames with both hardware and see which has the best performance.

Comment: You are going to have to learn by trial an error. Some scenes will render faster on GPU. Due to vRAM limitations some complex scenes will only render successfully on CPU. It all depends. Rendering on GPU will work more efficiently with larger tiles (over 128x128 pixels) whereas CPU rendering is more efficient with smaller ones (32x32 or smaller) The only advice I can give you is to try and see what works for you.

Comment: The description from Amazon of my video card is "EVGA GeForce GTX 960 4GB"  I had no idea what all the different options were.  My cpu is described as "Intel Core i7-5820K Haswell-E 6-Core 3.3GHz."  For simple stuff it's definitely faster using the GPU.  Use the Auto Tile Size add-on so that the GPU renders use an optimum tile size.  While it's rendering the mouse movement is jerky and not as responsive. In the User Preferences -> System you can also turn on Multisample for antialiased stuff in the 3d view, but read the section on that in the blender docs (I found it with a google search).

Answer (score -3):

I think a Intel Core i7 is faster on rendering than a GeForce GTX 960 4GB. If you had A GTX 980 I may had some doubt.