# Linux Ubuntu CUDA rendering not available

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I am using Linux Ubuntu 15.04, Blender 2.74, I have NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 which supports CUDA and 346.59 driver (latest driver available in my OS). When I open user preferences, CUDA is still not available. Why and how to fix that?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/cuda-rendering-on-linux-mint-17

Comment: OK! The werid thing: my CPU renders up a scene 4x faster than GPU :D

Comment: That's perfectly normal on machines with newer and multi-core processors and when using old or limited Nvidia Cards (like the ones in laptop computers)

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21321/gpu-rendering-is-equal-to-or-slower-than-cpu-rendering

Comment: Yeah, I have low-end GT 610, but quadcore 3.4 GHz i3 CPU:D

Comment: also check the size of your tiles. When rendering on GPU you might want to use tiles larger than 128 x 128. For CPU use smaller tiles like 32x32.

Comment: GT 610 card has only 48 Cuda cores, Don't even bother trying GPU rendering, stick to CPU ;)

Comment: Yeah! I am planning to get new GPU, but I even really can't afford to buy enaugh food(actually my parents, I am 14 years old with low income(sometimes for music, also for good grades in school):D)